# Что такое индекс mysql и как их использовать

Tags: mysql, sql

Можете привести понятный пример индекса в таблицах?
В документациях столько всего написано, это вводит в заблуждение.
Индекс - это и есть первичный или внешний ключ?

Comment: индекс это структура данных, обеспечивающая быстрый поиск. ключи реализуются на основе индексов, т.к. для проверки данных по правилам накладываемым ключем как раз нужен поиск

Comment: ну а можно примерчик?

Comment: А что конкретно вы хотите увидеть в примере?

Comment: И вы не пробовали в гугле забить ваш вопрос. первая же ссылка на википедию https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81_(%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

Comment: пробовал, ничего не понял из того описания

Comment: А что такое "понятный пример индекса". что именно вам с ним не понятно ? индекс делается с помощью `create index` в первичному и внешнему ключам он никакого отношения не имеет. Но когда вы создаете первичный ключ СУБД ссама создает индекс для обеспечения его работы, но это вас вообще то заботить сильно не доложно ибо вы просто понимаете что у вас есть ключ, а об индексе  при этом можете даже не думать (хотя полезно знать что он есть)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Если в кратце, то индекс, это поле по которому оптимизирован(ускорен) поиск.

Поскольку индекс занимает место, то индексировать нужно только те поля, по которым происходит выборка.

Допустим есть таблица.

```
CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    reg_date TIMESTAMP
)
```

`id` - уже индекс

Допустим вам нужен поиск по имени (firstname).

```
SELECT * FROM MyGuests WHERE firstname = "Вася"
```

тогда есть смысл добавить индекс по данному полю.

```
CREATE INDEX firstname_index ON MyGuests (firstname) USING BTREE;
```

Будет созданна "карта" которая позволет легко находить записи в оригинальном списке.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE

Для одной небольшой таблицы приемущество не будет очевидно < 1000 записей, но только до тех пор, пока вы не попытаетесь объеденит `join` несколько (3-4 уже достаточно) таблиц по неиндексированным полям. Убивает сервер на раз!

Comment: ну а можно примерчик хороший?

Comment: А что конкретно вы хотите увидеть в примере?

Comment: как добавляется и куда этот индекс, и как с помощью него сделать поиск этот по полю

Comment: @Sven Обновил ответ

Comment: а что такое BTREE ? и что далее происходит после этого CREATE INDEX firstname_index ON MyGuests (firstname) USING BTREE;   ?

Comment: @Sven Тип индекса, думаю в вашей ситуации роли не играет. Ещё может быт `HASH`, но по умолчанию для большинства таблиц `MySQL` будет `BTREE` по умолчанию

Comment: @Sven https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html#create-index-storage-engine-index-types

Comment: ок, и что же происходит после последней команды, допустим таких имён сто, что произойдёт?

Comment: Будет созданна "карта" которая позволет легко находить записи в оригинальном списке. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE

Comment: @Sven Вот это прочитайте, вот это и есть BTREE https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: я понял что такое BTREE - отсев значений грубо говоря...т .е. эта команда CREATE INDEX firstname_index ON MyGuests (firstname) USING BTREE; просто помогает поиску найти в этот значение SELECT * FROM MyGuests WHERE firstname = "Вася".  Я правильно понял?

Comment: @Sven Да, она создает на диске это самое дерево, с помощью которого облегчается поиск данных по этой (этим) колонке

Comment: @Sven именно.  btree сложность O(log n) у списка O(n). T.e. для 1000000 записей в первом случае надо перебрать ~14 раз во втором 1000000.

Comment: если до 500 например, то никто этот индекс и не создаёт таким образом CREATE INDEX firstname_index ON MyGuests (firstname) USING BTREE;?

Comment: @Sven Тут другая проблема, если вы будете просто выбирать из одной таблицы с 500 записями, то проблем нет. Но если вам нужно сделать `join` на 3-4 таблицы то, это просто убьет сервер.

Comment: Спасибо! В целом прояснилось видение об этом

Answer (score 10):

Вкратце, индексы создаются для повышения производительности поиска данных. Таблицы могут иметь огромное количество строк, которые хранятся в произвольном порядке. Без индекса поиск нужных строк идёт по порядку (последовательно), что на больших объемах данных отнимает много времени.

Индекс - обычно один или несколько столбцов таблицы и указателей на соответствующие строки таблицы, позволяет искать строки, удовлетворяющие критерию поиска. Ускорение работы с использованием индексов достигается в первую очередь за счёт того, что индекс имеет структуру, оптимизированную под поиск — например, в MySQL b-дерева. Индекс лучше использовать на тех столбцах таблицы, на которые вы чаще всего будете накладывать условия через `where column_name = ...`

---

Индекс создаётся по правилу:

```
create index название_индекса
on название_таблицы (название_столбца)
```

Например, у вас таблица называется `test`, где хранятся данные по городам России с улицами вида Город, Улица, Дом. Понятно, что строк в таблице при таком раскладе будет много. Если вы часто делаете выборку по определенному городу, например:

```
select *
from test
where city = 'Омск'
```

то, чтобы этот запрос отработал быстрее обычного, следует добавить индекс по вышеуказанному правилу:

```
create index city_index
on test (city)
```

Тогда тот же самый запрос

```
select *
from test
where city = 'Омск'
```

отработает гораздо быстрее, если столбец `city` будет проиндексирован.

Comment: получается это и есть внешний ключ?

Comment: @Sven нет, внешний ключ - это столбец для соединения с другими таблицами. Индекс - столбец, по которому можно задать условие и тогда запрос отработает гораздо быстрее.

Comment: ага, т. е  это комманда create index city_index
on test (city) просто чтобы упростить компу сделать поиск этот select *
from test
where city = 'Омск' и всё собственно?

Comment: Это create index city_index
on test (city)  можно(нужно) писать, если много в базе значений, а если до 500 например, то никто этот индекс и не создаёт таким путём create index city_index...?

Answer (score 7):

На пальцах можно объяснить так:

Когда Вы создаёте таблицу, добавляете в неё данные, то таблица разрастается и она выглядит как просто последовательный список, упорядоченный по тому как в неё данные добавлялись.

Когда данных мало, список маленький и все запросы к ней выполняются, почти, незаметно. Но когда количество записей в таблице начинает переваливать за миллион (в разных случаях по разном, но как пример миллион), то у Вас поиск уже идёт не так быстро и с добавлением всё новых и новых записей - ещё медленнее.

Это связано с тем, что когда Вы ищите какую-то запись, то просматриваются все записи, пока не дойдут до нужной.

Когда Вам это окончательно надоедает и Вы хотите что-нибудь сделать, то к Вам на помощь приходят **индексы**.

Индекс создаётся по какому-то определённому полю (можно по нескольким) по которому, обычно, выполняется поиск. Когда Вы создаёте индекс, то MySql (и любая другая БД) обходит все записи в таблице и строит дерево (скорее всего B-дерево или разновидность), в котором ключами выступает выбранное поле, а содержимым ссылки на записи в таблице.

И когда Вы делаете очередной свой `select` запрос по таблице, по полю для которого создали индекс MySql (и любая другая БД) знает что у неё есть индекс, по которому пройтись будет быстрее, нежели перебирать все записи и Ваш запрос будет направлен этому индексу и записи, удовлетворяющие условию, будут найдены гораздо быстрее, так как поиск по построенному дереву будет гораздо быстрее, нежели простой перебор всех записей.